# SQLAlchemy UNIQUE constraint failed on Many to Many Relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, relationship, user-management

When I create a user with User class, for example

`User(username='xxx',password='xxxx', role =[Role(name='Admin'),])`

Database will also add to Role table a row with name Admin.

The issue is when I create another user with role Admin and it will cast error UNIQUE constraint failed: roles.name. How can I prevent this ?

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///user.db'

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50),unique = False, nullable = False)
    role = db.relationship('Role',secondary = 'userroles', backref = db.backref('user',lazy = 'dynamic'))

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True)

class UserRole(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'userroles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey('roles.role_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

Comment: remove unique condition

Comment: that's an idea, but I think the name of role should be unique in roles table